# Magento - cart page blank caused by the following function (crashing app)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

Anyone have any ideas... there's like 15 places this function is getting called, every time it hits it seems to be the problem, it gets through the function but the serialized length of :

> echo "Length serialized: " . strlen(serialize($this->_items));

comes out to be about 8000 long.

```
 public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
    {
      if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter("quote_id", $this->getId())
            ;
           #$this->_items->setQuote($this);
        } 
        echo "Length serialized: " . strlen(serialize($this->_items));
        exit;


       return $this->_items;

    }
```

Comment: Is your question: What's causing the blank page? If so, you're going to get a bunch of answers telling you to turn on error reporting.

Comment: error reporting is on, infact i modified the error output to be more verbose... the problem is it isn't getting to the point where it can report an error on this.

Comment: I guess I figured stating the problem was as good as asking a question... question is how do i fix this?

Comment: Anything in the php or apache error logs? What's your memory limit at? What version of php are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like there is something weird in the item object. Like one of its members has a large object tied to it. I know that I had issues saving addresses to a session object. Maybe there is something you are doing outside of this that is attaching a large object that errors out. You could do the following to get the raw sql and run it on your database to see what comes back

```
public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
    {
      if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter("quote_id", $this->getId())
            ;
           #$this->_items->setQuote($this);
        } 
        echo (String)Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->getSelect();
        exit;


       return $this->_items;

    }
```

Comment: I basically get two rows returned from querying the database.

Comment: what are in those rows, does anything stand out as odd?

Answer (score 0):

i had same issues when i coded with Magento, it's linked to recursion, try var_dump() instead of echo()

Comment: So basically: $this->_items;
 is a ridiculously large object ( about 7000 lines of code when serialized ) thats causing time out in the browser since it gets called about 15 times during the add to cart process